# Determining a line in $\Bbb{R}^4$ that meets a given line and plane

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

> I have the equation for the first line in $\Bbb{R}^4$
> $$q : [1,3,1,1] + t(-1,2,-1,1)$$ where $t$ is a parameter. Then I have my plane given by these two equations
> $$\rho : x_1 + x_2 - x_3 -3x_4 = -2 \quad\text{and}\quad 2x_1 + x_2 -2x_4 = 5$$ I have to construct a line $p$ such that it intersects both the plane and the line $q$ and I know that it has the form of $p: A + s(1,1,2,0)$, where $A$ is some point.

Now I would know how to solve this if I was given the point instead of the vector but in this situation I have no idea.

Does anyone have any tips on how to proceed? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If we take any line with direction vector which is NOT parallel to the plane, then it will intersect the plane at some point. Try to visualize this, if you are having a hard time then visualize it in 3 dimensions instead. Now we simply need to ensure that this line will intersect q. To ensure this we can simply take any point on q and incorporate it into our line. The easiest point to take would be [1,3,1,1]. Now we just need to add to this any direction vector, not parallel to the plane, with a parameter.

In short, you already know how to solve this question if you were given a point instead of a line. So just do that! Take any point on q and solve as you usually would. Be sure to double check that it works